# React image slider does not work when i use useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-slider

I use react image slider [image slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-image-slider?activeTab=readme)

The issue is that when i store images paths like it's in code example it works ok

```
const images = [
  { url: "1.jpg" },
  { url: "2.jpg" }
];
```

But when i use it image slider does not work

```
    const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState([]);
    const fetchData = async () => {
            const images = await (await MessageService.getImagesById(location.state.message)).data; //here i get data from db
            const imagesPath = images.map(i => ({url: i.url}))
            setImagePath(imagesPath);
            console.log(imagesPath);//[ {url: "1.jpg"}, {url: "2.jpg"}]
}
        };
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchData();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

You can instead, for example, use a `useEffect` hook that is dependant on the relevant state in-order to see that the state value actually gets updates as anticipated.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(imagePath)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [imagePath])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "imagePath" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.